# HTaccess combined with AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, .htaccess

I've coded a brand new website as a side project and I'd like it to get indexed by Google and co.
The website has been made with AngularJS and optimised for SEO (at least, I tried to).

So far, Google has indexed each page  in a terrible way:

```
www.mywebsite.com/#!/post/title-of-this-post/
```

While the page has been declared in a `sitemap.xml`:

```
<url>
    <loc>http://mywebsite.com/post/title-of-this-post</loc>
    <lastmod>2015-08-04T00:00:00+00:00</lastmod>
    <changefreq>daily</changefreq>
</url>
```

The Website is using `HTML5 routes` to remove the `#!` symbols.
When I try to reach the indexed page, it goes to the home one. I need to remove the `trailing slash`.

So far, I've been able to create the following `HtAccess` file:

```
DirectoryIndex index.html
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

# BEGIN Seo crawler
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^_escaped_fragment_=(.*)$
RewriteRule ^$ /crawler.php$1 [QSA,L]
# END Seo crawler

# BEGIN sitemap and rss
RewriteRule ^sitemap.xml$ sitemap.php [L]
RewriteRule ^rss.xml$ rssfeed.php [L]
# END sitemap and rss

# BEGIN Remove trailing slash from URLs
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (.*)$
RewriteRule (.+)/$ http://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]
# END Remove trailing slash from URLs

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !index
RewriteRule (.*) index.html [L]
```

But this doesn't work.

- Typing `http://mywebsite.com/post/title-of-this-post/` will **correctly** redirect to `http://mywebsite.com/post/title-of-this-post` (Trailing slash is removed).
- Typing `www.mywebsite.com/#!/post/title-of-this-post/` will **sadly** redirect to `www.mywebsite.com/home`.
- Typing `www.mywebsite.com/#!/post/title-of-this-post` (Without the trailing slash) will **correctly** redirect to `http://mywebsite.com/post/title-of-this-post`.

Is there a way to achieve that ?

I'm using `Route UI` on my AngularJS Project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I've managed to fix it on my own:

Just add this piece of code to your `AngularJS` source:

```
app.config(function ($urlMatcherFactoryProvider) {
    $urlMatcherFactoryProvider.caseInsensitive(true);
    $urlMatcherFactoryProvider.strictMode(false);
});
```